# Is Indian Gooseberry a leguminous, nitrogen fixer plant?

Tags: legumes

Is [Indian Gooseberry (Amla)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllanthus_emblica) a leguminous, nitrogen fixer plant?

The leaf structure, arrangement seems to indicate so. I am not  sure. Any pointer would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the genus for Amla (*Phyllanthus*) is not in the Fabaceae family, then it is not a legume. As your link shows, it is in the Phyllanthaceae, which is not a known nitrogen-fixing family.

Comment: Thank you @Jurp. There by Moringa oleifera is also not legume as it does not belong to the Fabaceae family. Till now I was under the impression that Moringa oleifera is a nitrogen fixing pioneer trees.